# Streamlit Cannot insert Chinese charaters in the input text-box

Tags: web, chatbot, glm, streamlit, pinyin

I used streamlit to build up a web for chatbot.
However, when I insert the Chinese characters, I encountered two senarios:

1. I cannot insert Chinese;
2. I can insert Chinese but I have to invok the “input method” every time when I insert.

The above issues only happen with Chrome and Edge, but Firefox is working fine.

The similar issue also happen at the website:
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.text_input
[if you use Sougou pinyin input-method, you can recover my issue]

Can anyone help me figure out the issue.

Comment: Are you using `st.text_input` or `st.chat_input`? What happens when you try to insert Chinese characters?